# NullPointerException in WindowManagerImpl on Android OS 3.2

Tags: android

I got an null pointer exception on Android 3.2 emulator  on a simple Android project created by Wizerd with a service in separated process, when I switch between "Stretch to fill screen" to "Zoom to fill screen". This crash will *not* happen if the service is put into the same process with main activity, namely "android:process" attribute not specified. While it only happens when I add "android:process" to manifest file for my test service.

The exception is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    java.lang.NullPointerException
      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.reportNewConfiguration(WindowManagerImpl.java:427)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleUpdatePackageCompatibilityInfo(ActivityThread.java:2801)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2700(ActivityThread.java:122)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My test code:

## TestActivity.java (Generated by Wizerd)

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

## TestService.java (Most of the functions are empty)

```
Package com.test;

import android.content.ComponentName;

public class TestService extends Service {
    private boolean m_connected = false;

    private ServiceConnection m_connInitService = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnection(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            m_connected = true;
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        }
    };

    public static class TestServiceBinder extends Binder {
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new TestServiceBinder();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If I run the test app without service or with service in the same process the screen compatibility switch will not cause any problem. However, I do not understand why service can cause system exception during screen compatibility switch. Is this because service process is a non-UI process? Which could potentially triggers a bug inside the Android core code?

Comment: This also happens with my app on a XOOM tablet.  I also have a bound service to my activity in which this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I've found in the documentation the following thing:

> android:process
>
> If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a
> new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed
> and the service runs in that process. If the process name begins with
> a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of
> that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows
> components in different applications to share a process, reducing
> resource usage.

Thus, if you assign process name that starts with lowercase you should have permissions to do this. But I do not know where these permissions are checked. Maybe they are checked in the WindowManagerImpl and it cannot find this global process and thus returns null. This is just an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The reason causing this issue is Screen Compatibility Mode, see how to disable it for your app:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html#Disable